# Is there any simple way to protect the Android App and update it?

Tags: android

I developed an Android App and installed to three users' cellphones through Eclipse and USB connection. I don't want to put the App to google market. Now I got two problems:

1. How to protect the App and make it invalid in other cellphones. I know we cannot protect it 100%, I just don't want the App to be easily copied and run on other devices. What I have done was hard coding in my program to compare the AndroidID (save the AndroidID to a string and compare with current AndroidID). The problem is that if I have 100 users, I have to hard code 100 times.
2. How can I keep the users updated. Do I just upload the updated App to my own server and give them the link to download and install? In this case, the first problem comes out again: how to protect the App?

Comment: What do you mean by `AndroidID`?

Comment: Let users give you their "android id", sign that with your private key and give the signed file back to the user. Let app check that signed Android id = their own Id and that signed with your key.  The app just needs to have your public key. That should be pretty safe. Unless someone removes the check from your software.

Comment: @ Squonk  I got the AndroidID by using: <code private String ANDROID_ID;ANDROID_ID  = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); >

Answer (score 1):

The first thing in my mind is that you can set a password that app requires the first time it run after installation and give that password only to enabled users

Comment: Then what if the enabled users copy the App to other devices?

Comment: I didn't understand that enabled user can use the app only on one device. You can create a function to create a unique password from androidID, app give user androidID, user send you the ID (through app), you apply function and return user his password, user insert password, app validates password and enables device.

Answer (score 0):

you could make the application check for the presence of some pre-determined "key" file and distribute the file separately.

For updating the app can download new apk files and use an intent to send the user to the Package Installer so that they can choose whether or not to install.